# Why does MPlayer and MEncoder crash when opening a non-existant VCD track?

Tags: linux, crash, mplayer, mencoder, vcd

When I run a the command

```
$ mplayer vcd://2
```

on a VCD, it properly plays the video.

However if I run

```
$ mplayer vcd://3
```

or

```
$ mencoder vcd://3 -audio-preload 0.0 -o file.avi -mc 0 -oac copy -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=2000
```

my system immediately freezes. Interestingly, the CAPS lock LED in my keyboard flashes rapidly.

I'm not actually sure if it's a non-existant track or not but having it crash like this bewilders me and it seems to me that is it the only viable conclusion. Has there been any similar cases?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have something very similar:

Yesterday I upgraded several machines to the kernel 4.14.11.

Now all machines with AMD processors (not sure whether this is the crucial difference) freeze with flashing CAPS lock LED when I start different programs (olwm, clock). I haven't tried mplayer because I have currently booted the 4.14.9 kernel.

By the way, after one or two minutes of LED flashing my machines rebooted automatically.
In my opinion this is a kernel bug - and a severe one as well - for now I will stick to the 4.14.9 and wait for a new kernel.